# Solve the initial value differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following initial value differential equations $20y''+4y'+y=0, y(0)=3.2, y'(0)=0$.

To solve this I substituted $D= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$. and solved the auxiliary equation to get roots of $D$. and then the solution was 
$y= \exp\left(-\dfrac{x}{10}\right)(A \cos(x/5)+ B \sin(x/5))$
and tried to get the constants through given question. But I am not sure if the answer is correct.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Follow this link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i have edited the question. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct
$$ 20y′′+4y′+y=0$$
$$\implies 20r^2+4r+1=0$$
$$\Delta_r=16-4.20.1=-64=(8i)^2$$
$$r=\frac {-1\pm 2i}{10}$$
Therefore
$$y(x)=e^{-x/10}(K_1\cos(x/5)+K_2\sin(x/5))$$
Apply the initial conditions to find the constant $K_1 , K_2$